# Cordova `pause` event on iOS

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova

Is there any Cordova/DOM event that I can hook into on iOS when the user directly closes the app (by double-tapping the Home button and then swiping the app away)? The `pause` event does successfully fire when the Home button is pressed once and the app is sent to the background, but the double-tap+close seems not to do this -- at least in the emulator.

I am using the `pause` event to capture and store app state, so closing without saving will leave the user with no previous state to return to, or worse, an old state.

I am aware of the "iOS Quirks" warning in the documentation that says:

> In the pause handler, any calls to the Cordova API or to native plugins that go through Objective-C do not work, along with any interactive calls, such as alerts or console.log(). They are only processed when the app resumes, on the next run loop.

...but unless someone corrects me, I don't think this is the issue here

Comment: the documentation mentions the `resign` event for iOS which in my iOS 11 testing (with an async event listener function) is called on app minimize and tray open, but not lock or power off (possibly before my asyncs were finished)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question has been asked a lot on ionic forum and the consensus at the moment appears to be that this is not possible. I had this same desire for a time keeping app.  I ended up deciding to use setInterval at a frequency acceptable (for me 3 seconds was fine).  Agree this should be a feature